# Create table fails because PK constraint is already present

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, constraints, create-table

This create fails because there is already a `[PK_docEnum1ssThes]`

How can I delete `[PK_docEnum1ssThes]`?

`[PK_docEnum1ssThes]` is in `sys.objects`
`[docEnum1ssThes]` is in `sys.objects`
but `[docEnum1ssThes]` is not in SSMS
`drop table [docEnum1ssThes]` fails
`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[docEnum1ssThes] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_docEnum1ssThes]` fails

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[docEnum1ssThes]
(
    [searchID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [thesID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_docEnum1ssThes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
      [searchID] ASC,
      [thesID] ASC
    )
);
```

P.S. there was also an orphaned FK but I was able to delete it at the FK table.

What is interesting is that is the only user table with `dbo`.
I can change the name of the PK and create the table.
But the table name is then `docEnum1ssThes` not `dbo.docEnum1ssThes`

There error I get when I try and drop the table is:

> *Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
>   Cannot drop the table 'dbo.docEnum1ssThes', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.*

So this may be a permission thing but I am in Role serveradmin

In SSMS in View Object Explorer Details the table was listed
From there I was able to delete the table
How bizarre

Comment: Are you sure it's not associated with a different table? `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) FROM sys.objects WHERE name = N'PK_docEnum1ssThes';`

Comment: @AaronBertrand It is associated with [docEnum1ssThes]. But that table is not in SSMS and not in SysObjects.  If I try and drop it I get and error table does not exist.

Comment: check `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id)` too. SQL Server isn't going to lie to you about the presence of an object; clearly it's there but you must not be looking in the right place.

Comment: I was wrong - it is is SysObjects but not in SSMS

Comment: OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) = DBO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSMS in View Object Explorer Details the table was listed
From there I was able to delete the table
How bizarre